# Overwrite an old Ubuntu version with Ubuntu 16.04 in a dual-boot Windows-Linux laptop without affecting Windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a laptop which has the dual-boot option to run Windows 8 or Ubuntu 13.10. I want to overwrite the Ubuntu 13.10 partition with Ubuntu 16.04 without affecting the Windows 8 partition. What is the proper way to achive this and mantain the dual boot option?

Using the LiveCD I can see two options:

1. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager,
2. Something else

Which option should I use so not to end with a "triple boot"? I have already backed up my files of both operating systems.

Comment: You should get a  sub-option of 'Replace existing Linux partition' after choosing 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager'.